# I am trying open a Fragment From onOptionsItemSelected Method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to call a fragment from an activity. But unable. This is what I tried.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_search){
        SearchFragment searchFragment=new SearchFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,searchFragment,null).commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

And My main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context=".Controllers.MainActivity">
```

After trying the app does crash but its also not opening the fragment which I want.

The fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
tools:context=".SearchFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSearchFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And Fragment java is

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewSearch;
private RecyclerViewAdpater mAdpater;

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    mRecyclerViewSearch=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSearchFrag);
    mRecyclerViewSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mAdpater=new RecyclerViewAdpater(DataSevices.mChineseColors,getActivity());

    return view;
}

}
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Post crash log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Framlayout instead of Linear-layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: In MainActivity?

Comment: in MainActivity xml

Comment: If use FrameLayout then what about View Groups. Which are arranged using Linear Layout

Answer (score 0):

if you want some other components in your `MainActivity` , create a fragment for that.
and replace it.

in `activity_main.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

in your fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchFragment">

      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSearchFrag"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

create new fragment `fragment_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

and `MainFragment.java`

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

      //...

      return view;
  }
}
```